# how to get the first of each different class in div

Tags: jquery

How can i get the first instance of each div class within same div

example

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="class_0001">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0003">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0002">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0002"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0003"></div>
    <div class="class_0002"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
</div>
```

tried

```
$('div[div*="class_"]:first').each(function(){
       //do something
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ use NTH CHILD

Comment: if it were so easy lol , data and classes change and get reordered , so can target specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do that, but it's easy enough to iterate over all divs in reverse order and put them into a collection indexed by class. No need for a big library like jQuery for something this trivial:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('#wrap > div');
const divsByClass = {};
for (const div of [...divs].reverse()) {
  divsByClass[div.className] = div;
}
for (const div of Object.values(divsByClass)) {
  console.log(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="class_0001">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0003">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0002">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0002"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0003"></div>
    <div class="class_0002"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
</div>
```

If you really had to use jQuery as well, it wouldn't help the syntax much.

```js
const divsByClass = {};
for (const div of $('#wrap > div').get().reverse())  {
  divsByClass[div.className] = div;
}
for (const div of Object.values(divsByClass)) {
  console.log(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="class_0001">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0003">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0002">GET THIS</div>
    <div class="class_0002"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0003"></div>
    <div class="class_0002"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
    <div class="class_0001"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , tried that with a table layout and can't get it to work , changed div to tr , but i guess not that simple https://jsfiddle.net/7g5xne3q/8/

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid. A `<tr>` should be a child of a `<tbody>` - it won't be a direct child of the `<table>`. Inspect the browser's rendered HTML to see - the browser's inserting a `<tbody>`. As a result, nothing is matching your `#wrap > tr`.